# MOSS - get site usage summary by code

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2007

I want to build a WebService that shows two columns:
User Name , Url.

It will be a list of all the entrances to my sharepoint site.

I think to use the "MOSS usage service",
are there any articles about how to get to the service's data?
or maybe I need to deal here directly with the IIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to [enable usage analysis processing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541.aspx) (TechNet). Then for out-of-the-box options you already have, there are instructions in that TechNet article and you can also [use SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/ha101741361033.aspx).

Unfortunately the usage data cannot be accessed programmatically via the SharePoint API. You should set up IIS Log Parser instead. There is lots of information in this question [Exporting SharePoint usage log files into a database using LogParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181537/exporting-sharepoint-usage-log-files-into-a-database-using-logparser) and blog posts from [Todd Klindt](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=85), [Cory Burns](http://blogs.technet.com/corybu/archive/2008/02/26/sharepoint-iis-traffic-analysis.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!! seems to be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

First you must enable the site usage statistics in MOSS. Then you can use the GetUsageData method of SPWeb.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getusagedata.aspx