# Does Sharepoint track document downloads?

Tags: sharepoint

I know Sharepoint tracks modifications to files but does it track if a specific user opened a file for viewing?

Comment: Can you run SharePoint's IIS logs through web analytics software? 
http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/solutions/sharepoint-web-analytics-software/

You can't use Google Analytics for this because Google doesn't let you store usernames in the reports, and GA doesn't track direct file downloads. (it only tracks downloads that start with a trackable click)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, check out Item level Auditing and Audit log reports:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403(v=office.12).aspx#MOSS2007ItemLevelAudit_AuditingwithSharePointServer2007

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA010100005.aspx

Comment: Given you have Office SharePoint Server, not just SharePoint Services. For SharePoint services I came accross something called http://wssaudit.codeplex.com/ but i haven't used that myself.

Comment: There are third party tools available as well. http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit/summary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another option is parsing the IIS logs ([see this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181537/exporting-sharepoint-usage-log-files-into-a-database-using-logparser)).